# What is a single word for 'Reports and Charts'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sample:
To create a gantt chart, select the 'Reporting and Charting' module. Then, Press New... -> Gannt Chart.

---

The context is computer information processing, specifically generating table based document for printing (in the manner of a check register) or a graph (DJIA graph over time). I want to use this term as a module name (sibling modules include 'Projects', 'Activities', 'Schedules', 'Resources').

Simply using report or chart isn't feasible, as we are combining the report and chart domain, and don't wish to overload one of the terms.

Comment: If the chart and reporting module is designed to provide some synthetic information rather than detailed data, you may use the word "outlines".

Comment: If you're looking for the buzzword with which to search for different products: business intelligence.

Answer (score 1):

Reports and charts could both be considered types of ***summaries***.  Alternately, depending on what kind of reports you mean, both could be ***visualizations.***